# React-native : how to check if it's the user's first connection?

Tags: react-native, expo

I 'm new to react-native and I would like to set up my first page of the app with 
1- The user never logged in the app, I 'll present the app with some slides + go to signup page
2 -The user is already in => directly go to the user page
3 -The user is already in but the id is not correct

Can you guide me through it ?

For the first point I really don't know how to check if the user exist in my db

For the second and third points I thought I'd try :

```
onPressLogin(){
 fetch('linktomyAPI',{
     method: 'POST',
     headers:{
             'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
             'Accept':'application/json'
         },
         body: JSON.stringify({
             username:this.state.username,
             password: this.state.password,
         })
 })
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then((responseData) =>{
     if(responseData.error !== 1){ // verify the success case, as you didn't provide the success case i am using the error code
         this.setState({ // its recommended you verify the json before setting it to state.
             userdetail: responseData,
         })
         setTimeout(() => {
             Actions.Authentication();
         }, 2300);
         AsyncStorage.setItem('username', this.state.username); // its setItem not saveitem.
     } else {
         console.log(responseData);
         Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(responseData)); // Alerts doesn't allow arrays or JSONs, so stringify them to view in Alerts
     }
 }).catch((error) => {
     // handle catch
     console.log("error:"+JSON.stringify(error));
 });
 }
```

Do you think I can do this way, is that relevant?

Thanks for taking the time to answer me. I'm really new so I need help and explanations. Thanks !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the UserInfo to do. firstly, you have saved the user info in memory use `Session` js and in the device local file use `AsyncStore`. you already do it use the AsyncStore.

firstly save the user info into Session,the Session structure is:`{id:"dd333",name:"john"}`,

```
...
setTimeout(() => {
             Actions.Authentication();
         }, 2300);
        Session.id = res.id;
        Session.name = res.name;
        AsyncStorage.setItem('userinfo', Json.stringfy(res));
```

then you can show diffent page and condition.

```
// in the component which you want compoentDidMount
componentDidMount() {
 // here you can try to get it from AsyncStore if the Session is null.
 // then hanle it as the followng
if(Session.id == ""){
  //default it is "", it means the user does not login
} else if(Session.id != "222"){
  // the user id is not correct

} else {
  // here is the user login and id is correct

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer me, i'm going to try it !